# Standardise colour - value gradient across multiple data sets/maps

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

I have one country boundary layer with attribute table, which is joined to multiple standalone tables - and this contains four different data sets produced using zonal statistics as table and calculate field to calculate a risk score by region - I will map each data column individually on to the layer in question.

Within my attribute table, as I have joined four standalone tables, some of the rows contain  values as not every province has data for every species if the species range does not cover that province.

I would like to standardise the value-scale for each of the maps that I create so that they are comparable, as at the moment the highest value for one data set (4,800) and the highest value of another (1.2mill) are showing as the same colour.

The layer is a feature layer, and I will generate each of the maps by changing the field of display within the symbology tab and then create a new layout to export each map.
Working in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: It's three times the work to have four joined tables, and it causes value range issues as well. You can work around this with manual classification, an applying that symbology to all layers.

Comment: @Vince Am I right in thinking that manual classification would be done through adding expressions? I could remove three of the joins and just work with one, but when I come to work on the next set of data i'll still run into the same problem. I'd like to have them all on one map at once but some of the provinces are included in three of the data sets son it wouldnt work with the overlap

Comment: Manual classification is choosing the breakpoints on your own. Most of the algorithms are well documented, or you can generate a trivial dataset with the same min and max, then apply that to the oth layers. I join 10M row tables with 20M row tables all the time, so I'd probably find a way to merge them to make one layer.